# What is this plus sign and shorthand used in this SASS?

Tags: sass, bourbon

This was written a couple of years ago and little has been done with it since. I've been trying to find documentation for this notation and haven't found anything.

```
header
  +display(flex)
  +flex-flow(row-reverse wrap)
  +justify-content(flex-start)
  +align-items(center)
  +align-content(flex-start)
  width: 100%
```

I thought it was shorthand from Bourbon but there isn't any documentation about it. Is it from a previous version of Bourbon?

Comment: Weird flex, but okay. Isn't that just the old SASS way of using mixins? I don't see a lot of documentation on it, but if you go to https://sass-lang.com/guide and scroll to mixins and switch to SASS, it looks like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems old Bourbon flexbox mixins written with SASS syntax using `+` to `@include` a mixin.

Something like this:

```
@mixin bg-color
  background-color: #ff0000

h1
  +bg-color
```

In your case, the developer may have written something similar:

```
@import bourbon/bourbon

header
  +display(flex)
  +flex-flow(row-reverse wrap)
  +justify-content(flex-start)
  +align-items(center)
  +align-content(flex-start)
  width: 100%
```

These are the old Bourbon flexbox mixins: https://www.bourbon.io/docs/4/#flexbox